# What is the difference between aswMBR and the freely available avast antivirus?

Tags: anti-virus

Does aswMBR offer scan features not available in the free version of avast antivirus?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Avast's aswMBR page [here](http://public.avast.com/~gmerek/aswMBR.htm):

> aswMBR is the rootkit scanner that scans for TDL4/3, MBRoot (Sinowal),
>   Whistler and other rootkits.
>
> *This is a standalone cleaning tool, not a full-featured antivirus program. For full protection, please install avast! Free Antivirus*

Comment: Thanks. I did read that however does that mean that the freely available antivirus includes features and functions of aswMBR?

Comment: No.  It means this is a tools for cleaning Rootkits that got past your real-time scanner (Avast Free, or otherwise).  The latest Avast should detect the (known) rootkit variants and prevent them from being installed, but you'll still have to use this tool (or one like it) to clean them if they get in. ["The fundamental problem with rootkit detection is that if the operating system has been subverted, particularly by a kernel-level rootkit, it cannot be trusted to find unauthorized modifications to itself or its components"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rootkit#Detection)

Comment: So if the latest version of avast is used, it would be able to detect the same rootkits as awsMBR however possibly not remove them? Is that right?

Comment: Basically that is what I would expect, but it will probably only detect them when they _attempt_ to infect you, if it does manage to (ie a new variant Avast doesn't detect yet), then the Rootkit will (most likely) become invisible to Avast Free and undetectable.  The only way to confirm what's specifically detected and cleaned by each program's version at a specific point in time is to ask Avast. :)  My advice, keep Avast Free running, and if you suspect you have a Rootkit, run aswMBR (or alike) to make yourself feel better. :)